# query remote hiveserver2 got no response

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I have this `hive-site.xml` and its properties is added by [setting-up-hiveserver2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+up+HiveServer2)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
        <property>
          <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
          <value>jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.25:3306/hive_test?characterEncoding=UTF-8</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
          <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>

        <property>
          <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
          <value>root</value>
        </property>

        <property>
          <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
          <value>123123</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
          <value>false</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
          <value>/data/hive</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
          <value>/data/temp</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
          <value>false</value>
        </property>

        <property>
          <name>hive.querylog.location</name>
          <value>/home/hadoop/hadoopLogs/hive</value>
        </property>

        <property>
          <name>hive.server2.thrift.min.worker.threads</name>
          <value>5</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>hive.server2.thrift.max.worker.threads</name>
          <value>500</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
          <value>10000</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>hive.server2.thrift.bind.host</name>
          <value>cloud1</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>hive.server2.transport.mode</name>
          <value>binary</value>
        </property>

        <property>
        <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
        <value>NOSASL</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

And this is python code using `pyhs2`

```
import pyhs2
class HiveClient:
    def __init__(self, db_host, user, password, database, port=10000, authMechanism="PLAIN"):
        self.conn = pyhs2.connect(host=db_host,
                                  port=port,
                                  authMechanism=authMechanism,
                                  user=user,
                                  password=password,
                                  database=database,
                                  )
    def query(self, sql):
        with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(sql)
            return cursor.fetch()
    def close(self):
        self.conn.close()
    def main():
        hive_client = HiveClient(db_host='cloud1', port=10000,user='user', password='bblink',
                             database='default', authMechanism='PLAIN')
        result = hive_client.query('select * from bblink_bi_test3 limit 10')
        print result
        hive_client.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But when I run this python script ,there is nothing happend at hiverserver2 console or python client.

Can you help me ,please.

Comment: Is hiveserver2 running? Check port `10000` or check hive logs

Comment: Yes ,it is running,telent 10000 port is ok.

Comment: Is there other thing else to do ?